# Factors vs distinct factors

Tags: number-theory

I have a doubt in questions where we are asked to find the number of distinct factors of a number.

> Do we have to consider the total number of factors which are positive factors + negative factors or only the positive factors?

**Example:**

Q. Number of distinct factors of 36:
$\begin{cases}
\text{Positive factors: } 9\\
\text{Negative factors: } 9
\end{cases}$

So is the answer to the question be $9$ or $18$ ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Typically, this type of questions refers to positive factors only.